# Is it possible to create a dynamic filter/predicate in Mono/Flux?

Tags: java, project-reactor, spring-webclient

The app is a simple processing - reading data, filtering it, process and write filtered data.

Here is a simple code which runs without any issue:

```
  void run() {
    Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(200))
        .filter(value -> getPredicate().test(value))
        .flatMap(this::writeData)
        .subscribe();
  }

  private Predicate<Long> getPredicate() {
    return value -> value % 2 == 0;
  }
```

Is it possible to have dynamic predicate which will be retrieved from remote web service with periodic requests?
If possible - how to use Mono<Predicate> inside .filter() and keep it non-blocking

For example replacing getPredicate() with below:

```
  private Mono<Predicate<Long>> getPredicateFromRemoteServer() {
    return webClient.get()
        .uri("/filters/1")
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(Filter.class)
        .map(this::mapToPredicate)
        .cache(v -> Duration.ofMinutes(10), ex -> Duration.ZERO, () -> Duration.ZERO);
  }

  private Predicate<Long> mapToPredicate(Filter filter) {
    // here will be converting filter object into predicate
    return value -> value > 5;
  }
```

Ideally I would like to avoid cache(Duration.ofMinutes(10)) because filter could be updated each minute, or each day... and once filter is updated my service get notified, but I didn't find a way to invalidate cache externally, that's why Duration.ofMinutes(10) is used for some approximate invalidation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, perhaps you could write the pipeline a bit differently. Instead of aspiring to return a new `Predicate` every time your process an item in your stream by calling `getPredicateFromRemoteServer()`, you could make the function itself your predicate. Pass the value you are processing from the stream and make it return a `Mono<Boolean>` with the answer and use that in a `filterWhen` pipe in your pipeline.

For example, somewhat like this:

```java
private Mono<Boolean> isWithinThreshold(int value) {
    return webClient.get()
        .uri("/filters/1")
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(Filter.class)
        .map(filter -> filter.threshold <= value)
        .cache(v -> Duration.ofMinutes(10), ex -> Duration.ZERO, () -> Duration.ZERO);
  }
```

Then in your main pipeline you can do:

```java
Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(200))
        .filterWhen(value -> isWithinThreshold(value))
        .flatMap(this::writeData)
        .subscribe();
  }
```